# For a set E, define interior, exterior, and boundary points

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

a) Consider the real line $\mathbb{R}$. The $\epsilon$-neighborhood of a point $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$ is defined as $I_{\epsilon}(x_{0}) = (x_{0} - \epsilon, x_{0} + \epsilon)$. For a set E $\subset\mathbb{R}$ define interior, exterior, and boundary points. Give the definition of open and closed sets.

b) Give a constructive description of all open subsets of the real line. Prove your statement.

So in part (a), I'm not sure how the subset E relates to $I_{\epsilon}(x_{0})$. And by the wording I am not sure if I need to define open and closed sets using the subset E.

In part (b), I am not sure what a constructive description is and much less how to prove it.

I am not sure if this helps but it is for a complex analysis class even though it's only referring to the real line.

Comment: It's exploring basic concepts of topology. As in letter (a) it's asking for definitions, I'm assuming you were giving some study material or at least an heuristic case so you could try and define meaningfully what is interior, exterior and boundary. Otherwise the question seems just...arbitrary...

Answer (score 1):

Let $(X,\mathcal{T}) $ be a topological space.
General definition of *open set*
$$
A\text{ open}\iff A\in\mathcal{T}
$$ 
General definition of *closed set*
$$
A\text{ closed}\iff A^c\in\mathcal{T}.
$$ 
Now, in your case $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathcal{T}$ is (supposedly) the topology induced by the standard metric on $\mathbb{R}$,
$$
d(x,y)=|x-y|\quad x,y\in \mathbb{R}
$$
and this defines the a set $A$ to be open if 
$$
 \forall x\in A\ \exists \epsilon>0 \text{ s.t. } I_\epsilon(x)\subset A\iff A\in\mathcal{T}\iff A\text{ open}.
$$ 
From this you should sort out part (b).
Now note how similar this definition with the *open(!) interval* $I_\epsilon(x)$ and the following definition of *interior* are.

Definition of *interior* of $A\subset X$,
$$
Int(A)=\{x\in X: \exists U\in\mathcal{T}\text{ s.t. }x\in U\text{ and }  U\subset A\}
$$
Definition of the *closure* of $A\subset X$,
$$
Cl(A)=\{x\in X: \forall U\in\mathcal{T}\text{ s.t. }x\in U\quad U\cap A\neq\emptyset\}
$$
(Shortcut-)Definition  of the *boundary* of $A\subset X$,
$$
\partial(A)=Cl(A)\backslash Int(A)
$$
For part (a) I already gave you the definition of open and closed, you can now give the definitions of closure, interior and boundary of $E\subset\mathbb{R}$ translating the general ones I gave you.

(Hope it helps, consider that if you do not know the basics of topology my answer might be hardly readable)